# About Lambda.... semicolon

Tags: java

if function has return value --> can skip semicolon (;)

```
(int a, int b) -> { return a > b ? a : b ;} ----> (int a, int b) -> a> b ? a : b
```

but.. my question is..

```
Supplier<Integer> s = ()-> (int)(Math.random()*100)+1;
Consumer<Integer> c = i -> System.out.print(i + ", ");
Predicate<Integer> p = i -> i % 2 == 0;
```

i try to except ( ; ) but it brings Exception..

why ( ; ) can't skip?

Comment: In your 3 examples `;` represents the end of line. Like `int a = 10;`. but instead of `int a` you have `Predicate<Integer> p` and instead of `10` you have `i -> i % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semi-colon is your 3 examples is not part of the lambda expressions.

You have 3 assignment statements, each of them assigning a lambda expression to a variable.

The semi-colon is a required character at the end of each statement.

If you passed your lambda expressions directly as an argument to a method, the semi-colon wouldn't be needed.

For example:

```
IntStream.range(0,10).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)...
```

Of course, there would still be a semi-colon at the end of this stream pipeline statement.

Comment: Sorry.. Can i see more example??